# Terminal - Why the exit command of grep is 0 even if a match is not found?

Tags: shell, terminal, grep, exit-code

I have this command:

```
grep -E '^nothing' List.txt | echo $?
```

Here grep doesn't match anything and I simply output its exit code. According to documentation of grep:

> Normally the exit status is 0 if a line is selected, 1 if no lines
>   were selected, and 2 if an error occurred. However, if the -q or
>   --quiet or --silent option is used and a line is selected, the exit status is 0 even if an error occurred. Other grep implementations may
>   exit with status greater than 2 on error.

But:

```
prompt:user$ grep -E '^nothing' List.txt | echo $?
0
prompt:user$
```

But why do I get 0 as output even if the match doesn't exist, should't I get the expected 1 exit code?

Comment: Replace `|` by a `;`.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish anyway?  The usual idiom is `if grep -qE '^nothing' list.txt; then ...`

Comment: Yes I am using grep in a bash script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
grep -E '^nothing' List.txt | echo $?
```

By using single `|` you are sending output of `grep` to `echo` which will always print exit status of previous command and that will always be 0 whether pattern is found or not.

You can use `grep -q`:

```
grep -qE '^nothing' List.txt
```

As per `man grep`:

```
 -q, --quiet, --silent
         Quiet mode: suppress normal output.  grep will only search a file until a match
         has been found, making searches potentially less expensive.
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! It works. Just a clarification. When you say `which will always print exit status of previous command and that will always be 0 whether pattern is found or not.` but if the pattern is not found, greps exits with one, so shouldn't it be one?

Comment: `grep -E '^nothing' List.txt | echo $?` prints exit status of the command that was executed **before** `grep` not this `grep` command.

Comment: All right, thanks that was what I needed to understand!

Comment: grep -s is recommended instead of -q for Posix compat.